# The inner workings of motors and generators

Tags: back-emf

Inductive components like motor winding resist sudden changes in current. That's because the magnetic field caused by the current needs time to build up or decrease. That means that when current is flowing and this is suddenly cut off, the winding will try to maintain that current, and becomes a power source generating a voltage to be able to do so. It gets its power from the built up magnetic field.
 At this point what happens to the magnetic field?

Comment: The field decreases and eventually becomes zero. As a consequence, the induced emf and current that this generates (if there’s a closed loop) also decay to zero.

Comment: A motor winding, with a moving rotor, is not an 'inductive component' because it is doing work.   That means it consumes power, like a resistor.

Answer (score 1):

> It gets its power from the built up magnetic field. At this point what
>   happens to the magnetic field?

What is "held" in the magnetic field is energy not power and, when that energy reduces to zero, the current also arrives at zero.

When the current becomes zero there *may* be a little bit of magnetic field that remains and this depends on the inductor core material and how much the original driving current saturated the core.

What remains of the magnetic field cannot be converted to energy and represents a loss of energy.